# Separating out bad data rows in Apache Spark/Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, etl, databricks

I'm using Apache Spark (via DataBricks and Scala) to transform some data from a raw form (in an SQL database, but with everything as an uncleansed VARCHAR) into a structured from (in another SQL database, but with correct types and values validated, etc).

This is generally working fine, but many of the built in Spark functions (e.g. `.cast(IntegerType)`) will just set unparseable values to null. Is there a way to have "bad" rows logged and separated out instead (for further investigation)?

Note, I can't just filter out null values after as the data contains many valid nulls that should be included.

Comment: you can have map transformation and inside **Map** have custom logic to clean fields. if cleaning of any particular field fails you can log it and eat the exception.  and one more point is you can also add new column to finalDF with type as Map<fieldName,errormessage> ...  write it down to separate folder to check issues.

Comment: Any reproducible example? hard to imagine.